# Syntax for converting tuple into string with Merge in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, merge, error-000732, syntax

I have a tuple of unknown elements, which I want to convert into a string for using in the arpy command

```
arcpy.Merge_management([Input1, Input2, ..., Inputx], "D:\\test.shp")
```

In my example I have only three elements in the tuple and tried to convert this element into one string as the inputs for the command. I do this with following command:

```
Input = "['" + "', '". join((str(n) for n in args)) + "']"
```

If I display the variable [Input], I get a plausible result.

```
['D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_LAZ_pre.shp', 'D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_AVS_pre.shp', 'D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_DEM_pre.shp']
```

Unfortunately I got always following error message, when I tried to integrate the variable into the Merge command:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(Input, "D:\\test.shp")

ERROR 000732: Input Datasets: Dataset '['D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_LAZ_pre.shp', 'D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_AVS_pre.shp', 'D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_DEM_pre.shp']' does not exist or is not supported
```

Can anyone help to solve the hopefully small problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just glancing at this, it looks like you have escaped only half of your backslashes?

> D:\\Buildings\\Gemeinden\8537\8537_Change_Detection_TLM_LAZ_pre.shp'

I would suggest trying a real string, escaping all the back slashes, or using forward slashes.

reference: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/setting-paths-to-data.htm

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to convert to a string, you can directly supply a tuple or list as the argument.

[From the examples:](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm)

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.Merge_management(["majorrds.shp", "Habitat_Analysis.gdb/futrds"], "C:/output/Output.gdb/allroads")
```